# Error subprocess con Java y Python

Tags: python

Saludos tengo una sentencia la cual envia diferentes parametos hacia la terminar e invoca un archivo **JAR** al parecer lo invoca pero al momento de retornar respuesta me genera este error:

```
File "/var/www/html/facturacion/ventas/views.py" in GrabarVenta
  374.         tree = ET.XML(string_xml)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py" in XML
  1300.     parser.feed(text)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py" in feed
  1642.             self._raiseerror(v)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py" in _raiseerror
  1506.         raise err

Exception Type: ParseError at /ventas/grabar_venta
Exception Value: syntax error: line 1, column 0
```

este error se debe a que de mi invocacion debe retornar un string de un xml firmado en JAVA al parecer no lo retorna y me retorna esto al invocarlo:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...](to execute a class)
 or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
```

El comando con el que invoco a java es:

```
PATH_FIRMA_ABSOLUTA = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),'static/SRI/mifirma.p12')
PATH_FIRMAR_JAVA = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),'static/SRI/firmaXadesBes.jar')

file_pk12 = PATH_FIRMA_ABSOLUTA
password = 'Rgberv1792'
JAR_PATH = PATH_FIRMAR_JAVA
JAVA_CMD = 'java'
ds_document = False
#xml_str = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>"
PATH_XML_ABSOLUTO =  os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),path_xml_generado)
tree = etree.parse(str(PATH_XML_ABSOLUTO))
xml_str = etree.tostring(tree, encoding='utf8', method='xml')

command = [
    JAVA_CMD,
    '-jar',
    JAR_PATH,
    xml_str,
    base64.b64encode(file_pk12),
    base64.b64encode(password)
]

p = subprocess.Popen(
    command,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    shell=True
)
res = p.communicate()
```

**Actualizacion**

Realizando de la siguiente manera:

```
from lxml import etree
    import shlex, subprocess
    import base64  # encriptar archivo
    from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
    import io

    PATH_FIRMA_ABSOLUTA = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),'static/SRI/betty_elena_romo_vega.p12')
    PATH_FIRMAR_JAVA = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),'static/SRI/firmaXadesBes.jar')

    file_pk12 = PATH_FIRMA_ABSOLUTA
    password = 'Rgberv1792'
    JAR_PATH = PATH_FIRMAR_JAVA
    JAVA_CMD = 'java'
    ds_document = False
    PATH_XML_ABSOLUTO =  os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),path_xml_generado)
    tree = etree.parse(str(PATH_XML_ABSOLUTO))
    xml_str = etree.tostring(tree, encoding='utf8', method='xml')

    command = [
        JAVA_CMD,
        '-jar',
        JAR_PATH,
        xml_str,
        base64.b64encode(file_pk12),
        base64.b64encode(password)
    ]

    print command

    p = subprocess.Popen(
        command,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        #shell=True
    )
    res = p.communicate()

    # guardar xml firmado
    documento_firmado = res[0]
    print "DOCUMENTO JAVA FIRMADO"
    print documento_firmado

    # guardar xml firmado
    string_xml = documento_firmado

    tree = ET.XML(string_xml)
```

Funciona locamente en modo deployment con apache y mod_wsgi, pero al subir al servidor Amazon que esta en modo deploy con apache y mod_wsgi me genera el error:

```
Traceback:  

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/var/www/html/facturacionelectronica/ventas/views.py" in GrabarVenta
  362.             stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py" in __init__
  711.                                 errread, errwrite)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py" in _execute_child
  1327.                 raise child_exception

Exception Type: OSError at /ventas/grabar_venta
Exception Value: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Gracias cualquier sugerencia..!!

Comment: Me intriga cómo interpretará el shell `xml_str` después que Popen escape la cadena. Intenta entrecomillar `xml_str` con `"`. ¿El comando corre bien directamente desde shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si usas `shell=True` y pasas un iterable como `args` **solo el primer item es considerado como comando a ejecutar**, el resto son argumentos para la propia consola (no para el ejecutable)

De la propia [documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

> On Unix with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. If args is a string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell. This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be when typed at the shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself.

Podemos traducirlo algo así:

> En Unix con `shell = True`, la consola por defecto es `/bin/sh`. Si `args` es una cadena, la cadena especifica el comando que se ejecutará a través dela consola. Esto significa que la cadena debe tener exactamente el mismo formato que cuando se escribe en la consola. Esto incluye, por ejemplo, entrecomillar o escapar  nombres de archivos con espacios en ellos. **Si `args` es una secuencia, el primer elemento especifica la cadena del comando, y cualquier elemento adicional se tratará como argumentos adicionales para la propia consola**.

En tu caso, lo que Python ejecuta es en realidad:

```
subprocess.Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', 'java', '-jar', ...])
```

Por lo que en realidad solo ejecuta el comando `java`, lo cual retorna la ayuda de uso simplemente.

En definitiva, si tienes que usar `shell = True` tienes que pasar el comando como una cadena, puedes usar `str.join` para no tener que modificar mucho tu código:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
    " ".join(command),
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    shell=True
)
```

**Edición**

Aunque lo comento arriba (**la cadena debe tener exactamente el mismo formato que usarías en la consola**), he pasado por alto la buena observación de @Sal en su comentario. Es de esperar que necesites englobar entre comillas la cadena que representa el argumento `xml_str`. Lo mismo para el resto de argumentos (como las cadenas en base64) de ser necesario. Puedes usar `str.format` para tal fin y eventualmente escapar cualquier comilla simple que pueda existir dentro de la cadena:

```
xml_str = "'{}'".format(xml_str.replace("'", "'\\''"))
```

En definitiva, asegurate que la cadena resultante es válida como comando para la consola, Python la pasa a sh tal cual. Si se usa Python 3 se puede hacer uso de `shlex.quote` junto a `str.join`:

```
" ".join(shlex.quote(c) for c in command)
```

> En Python 3.8 (en beta ahora) se ha agregado [`shlex.join`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/shlex.html#shlex.join) que actúa como método inverso a `shlex.split` y que permite construir la cadena a partir de la lista de tokens, justamente lo que buscamos.

Comment: Gracias he hecho algunos cambios y en mi Pc local en modo deploy funciona perfecto pero al subir al servidor no lo hace me genera un nuevo error.

Comment: Puede que la pregunta sea tonta, pero ¿tienes Java instalado en el servidor? ¿Puedes via ssh por ejemplo verificarlo con `$ java -version`?

Comment: Buena pregunta, se me habia pasado comprobar algo tan basico ahorita lo compruebo